# How to apply Image TranslateTranform to an Image by step (Jump a few Pixel)

Tags: c#, rendertransform

I currently using the TranslateTransform on an image by code in my App and it's working correctly.

But I would like the image to move by step, let's say jump 10 or 20 pixel on each movement. Is there a way to do this. This to give a retro flavor to the movement.

I was thinking something like TranslateTransform.Step = 10;

```
            Duration durationX = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 600);
            Duration durationY = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400);

            DoubleAnimation moveX = new DoubleAnimation();
            moveX.Duration = durationX;
            moveX.To = ((ImgCanvasCoordinates[cardSource][0] - ImgCanvasCoordinates[cardTarget][0]) * -1);
            DoubleAnimation moveY = new DoubleAnimation();
            moveY.Duration = durationY;
            moveY.To = ((ImgCanvasCoordinates[cardSource][1] - ImgCanvasCoordinates[cardTarget][1]) * -1);

            Storyboard story1 = new Storyboard();
            story1.Children.Add(moveX);
            story1.Children.Add(moveY);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(moveX, imgGhost);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(moveY, imgGhost);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveX, "(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveY, "(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)");

            story1.Begin();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Preview of the step animating effect]

You can use a custom `EasingFunction` to achieve this.

By writing an `EasingFunction` you can fully control the movement of animation. I've written a `StepEasingFunction` as shown below:

```
public class StepEasingFunction : EasingFunctionBase
{
    public double NormalizedStep { get; set; }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new StepEasingFunction {NormalizedStep = NormalizedStep};
    }

    protected override double EaseInCore(double normalizedTime)
    {
        var stepIndex = Math.Round(normalizedTime / NormalizedStep);
        return NormalizedStep * stepIndex;
    }
}
```

Then, just add an EasingFunction assigning to the animations:

```
moveX.EasingFunction = new StepEasingFunction {NormalizedStep = 0.2};
moveY.EasingFunction = new StepEasingFunction {NormalizedStep = 0.2};
```

Then, how to calculate the value of the `NormalizedStep` property?

You said that you want a 10-pixel movement for each step, so calculate the step total count and use `1 / stepTotalCount` to calculate the final `NormalizedStep` property.

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm getting this message after adding the Class StepEasingFunction: EasingFunction Base does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement EasyFunction in my WPF code.I'm getting error on EaseInCore and CreateInstanceCore: no suitable method found to override and on Freezable: Freezable does not exist in the namesape.

Comment: I made the mistake of setting the WPF tag instead of UWP. That's explains why  I was not able to use the code. Very good answer for WPF coders. UWP needs to be improved...

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to extend a custom EasingFunction in UWP. That is we have to write many helper codes to achieve such behavior. If it should be done, we can start a new **UWP** question to collect more solutions. See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81e9d88b-70c7-4ba2-92bf-7c3890b91f81/uwpeasingfunctionbase-uwp-how-to